# How to killprocess in Android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) so that 'force stop' is grayed out in settings?

Tags: android, resources, kill, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, quit

I have a 'quit' button in my app. When user quits, I finish() all my acivities on the stack and then call android.os.Process.killProcess() in the base activity such that when the user goes into their Application settings and look at my application, the 'Force Stop' button is grayed out (essentially indicating that it is no longer running).  This works fine except for on Ice Cream Sandwich where the 'Force Stop' button in settings isn't grayed out unless I press it to 'Force Stop' my app. Is there some way that I can make it so that that button isn't clickable in settings (and so that the user doesn't think that it's still running)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: Yes, I have read that post, thanks. However, it doesn't answer my question. I already have the app behaving a certain way on pre-ICS devices.. just curious as to how to make it behave the same on ICS.